# How do I work with DataContexts in Breezejs?

Tags: datacontext, breeze

In the plans for my app there is a central cache module. In this module there are what I call Contexts, there are about 20 of them. Each Context manages its own set of what I call Inject objects (likely what Breeze calls Entities), which hold values that specific functions in the app use. Each Context is like its own smaller DB inside the wrapping cache module.

My main question is that the Breeze tutorial talks about the DataContext that wraps its own EntityManager, it seems similar to my Context but I can not more information on it except for the brief mention. Is the DataContext a concept only or an actual object in the Breeze API?

Answer (score 2):

Jay is talking about the server side of things in .NET. Perhaps you are talking about the client-side JavaScript?  If so, read on; if not ... stick with Jay's answer.

In our client-side JavaScript apps we often write a module that insulates the ViewModels from the Breeze `EntityManager`. Such a module might be called "dataservice.js" in one sample; it could be called "datacontext.js" in another sample. The concept is the same: you're trying to encapsulate the data access details (which involve BreezeJS components such as the `EntityManager`) so that the ViewModels work with a simpler, more intentional interface.

These JS modules are not part of Breeze. They are merely a recommended approach to structuring your application.

You can write as many flavors of these "datacontexts" as you like. Each can have its own `EntityManager` instance, which caches its own set of entities and you could think of that cache as "smaller [in memory] database" if you like. this kind of "contextualizing" for distinct workflows is pretty common in business apps. You'll see us talk about "sandbox editors" for example; each sandbox is its own "context".

You often need to copy entities from one "context" to another (rather than round-trip to the server). That's easy to do with the `EntityManager.exportEntities` and `EntityManager.importEntities` methods. You'll find examples in the **DocCode sample**.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze currently provides two server side implementations that wrap a "conceptual" context.  The **EFContextProvider** is used for wrapping an EF DbContext or ObjectContext, and a base **ContextProvider** that can be used to wrap any collection of objects.  There is an example titled "NoDb" in the breeze samples zip that shows how the ContextProvider can be used to simply wrap a collection of queryable objects.  These two classes are available in the Breeze.WebApi project within any of the zips on the breeze downloads page.

Again, the NoDb sample and associated docs should make this concept a bit clearer.